# Stopping a message box from popping up

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, message

I have this VBScript to make a message box appear:

```
x=msgbox("The message" ,6, "Title")
```

When I run it, the message pops up with the popup effect. How do I make it appear without this effect? Preferably without disabling it completely (just for this message box.) The vbs is been executed from a batch script.

This is the batch code: `@echo off % %Temp%\done.vbs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force it to run under `cscript` instead of `wscript`. 
Since you are calling the script manually, you can place `cscript` infront of it:

```
@echo off % cscript %Temp%\done.vbs
```